# Does heavier car need more aerodynamic downforce in turn than lighter car for same cornering speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram, drag, aerodynamics

When a car turns, the frictional force $F_f = (mg\mu + A\mu)$, where A is aerodynamic downforce and $\mu$ the friction coefficient, needs to match the centrifugal force $F_c = m \times V^2/r$. If the car's mass increases by 20%, both the frictional and centrifugal forces will increase by the same percentage.
Does heavier car need more aerodynamic downforce in turn than lighter car for same cornering speed?

(Assumption is that car produce downforce,I know that car can make a turn without any downforce.)

Comment: In general, a car does not _need_ aerodynamic forces to turn.

Comment: After checking the comment of @JAlex, I realised that I had misunderstood the question, so I delete my answer.

Comment: @JAlex in general, all cars produce non zero aerodynamic force, lift or downforce...car is not symetric object

Comment: @user628075 - yes, but they do not _need_ downforce or lift to turn. Mechanical grip suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Given a turn of fixed radius $r$, and a required corner speed of $V$, such that the centripetal acceleration is $$a_c = \frac{V^2}{r}$$, you can back solve for any *additional* downforce $A$ needed to sustain this turn, if the mechanical grip is $\mu$, from $a=F/m$

$$ \frac{V^2}{r} = \frac{ \mu ( m g + A) }{m} $$

with solution

$$ A = m \left( \frac{V^2}{\mu \,r} - g  \right)$$

which indeed shows the proportionality with mass $m$, given all else remains the same.

Comment: If car has more weight at rear axle that mean we must produce more downforce at rear axle?

Comment: Definitely yes,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a heavier car would typically need more downforce than a lighter car to make a turn at the same speed.

Note that the centrifugal force $F_c$ is proportional to its mass and an increase in the car's mass leads to a corresponding increase in $F_c$. To avoid skidding, the frictional force $F_f$ must compensate accordingly. If only the car's weight increases and the downforce remains constant, the total frictional force might be insufficient. Consequently, for the heavier car to turn at the same speed as before, an increase in the aerodynamic downforce $A$ is required.

Comment: You say No, but the answer is actually Yes you need more aero force to contribute the same centripetal acceleration.

Comment: @Alex I edit  my question in text because it is opposite from what title ask(just confuse)...so you just change No into Yes and your answer is correct.

Comment: @user628075 done it!